# SQL query error - enclosed quotation mark and incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sapb1

We have a query in our SAP Business One program which a former colleague created.

The query has been working fine every month since it was created in 2015 but today it is throwing up errors and we have no SQL experts here.

**The error:**

```
1). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'SALES PROMOT'. 2). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SALES PROMOT'.  'Document' (RDOC)
```

**The query:**

```html
DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @OINV VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @ORIN VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @From varchar(15)
DECLARE @To varchar(15)
Set @From =/* SELECT convert(varchar(15),Max(T0.DocDate),112) FROM OINM T0 WHERE T0.DocDate > */ convert(varchar(15),'[%0]',112)
Set @To =/* SELECT convert(varchar(15),Max(T0.DocDate),112) FROM OINM T0 WHERE T0.DocDate > */ convert(varchar(15),'[%1]',112)
 
 
SET @OINV =  isnull( STUFF((Select  ',' + convert(varchar(10),Docentry) from OINV
  where CANCELED <>'N' FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ,0)
SET @ORIN =  isnull(STUFF((Select  ',' + convert(varchar(10),Docentry) from ORIN
  where CANCELED <>'N' FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ,0)
SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + ltrim((ItmsGrpNam)) from OITB
ORDER BY '],[' + ltrim((ItmsgrpNam)) FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
 
SET @Query = 'Select *  from (Select T0.CardCode, T0.CardName, T6.[GroupName], T4.ItmsGrpNam,sum(T1.LineTotal) as Sal from
OINV T0 Inner join INV1 T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
Inner Join OFPR T2 on T2.AbsEntry = T0.FinncPriod
Inner Join OITM T3 Inner Join OITB T4 On T4.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsgrpCod on T1.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode Inner Join OCRD T5 On T5.CardCode=T0.CardCode inner join OCRG T6 On T6.[GroupCode]=T5.[GroupCode]
Where convert(varchar(15),T0.Docdate,112) >= convert(varchar(15),'+@From+',112)
and convert(varchar(15),T0.Docdate,112) <= convert(varchar(15),'+@To+',112)
and t0.docentry not in ('+@OINV+')
group by T0.CardName ,T4.ItmsGrpNam,T0.CardCode, T6.[GroupName]
 
union all
 
Select T0.CardCode, T0.CardName, T6.[GroupName], T4.ItmsGrpNam,sum(-T1.LineTotal) as Sal from
ORIN T0 Inner join RIN1 T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
Inner Join OFPR T2 on T2.AbsEntry = T0.FinncPriod
Inner Join OITM T3 Inner Join OITB T4 On T4.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsgrpCod on T1.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode Inner Join OCRD T5 On T5.CardCode=T0.CardCode inner join OCRG T6 On T6.[GroupCode]=T5.[GroupCode]
Where convert(varchar(15),T0.Docdate,112) >= convert(varchar(15),'+@From+',112)
and convert(varchar(15),T0.Docdate,112) <= convert(varchar(15),'+@To+',112)
and t0.docentry not in ('+@ORIN+')
group by T0.CardName ,T4.ItmsGrpNam, T0.CardCode, T6.[GroupName]

 
) src
PIVOT (sum(Sal) for ItmsgrpNam IN ('+@listCol+')) AS pvt'
EXECUTE (@Query)
```

Could anyone advise how I can begin to troubleshoot this or see any blatant errors in the code?

Comment: Remove one part at the time to find where the problem part is.

Comment: It looks like you're running SAP on SQL, have you tried running the query in SSMS? You will have to change it a bit to get rid of the SAP specific assignments `SET @FROM = ` and `SET @TO = `

Answer (score 0):

What this query is doing is building a dynamic query string in `@query` which gets executed right at the end. Somewhere in the query it's adding a value that has an unclosed quotation mark.

Rather than having `EXEC(@query)`, you can use `SELECT @query` to return the dynamic query string, inspect it, find where it went wrong and fix the record in question.

My guess would be one of the Item Group Names in `OITB.ItmsGrpNam` has a quotation mark in it that will need to be removed or escaped properly.